# AVAudioSession manipulate sound output

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I'm  using `AVSoundSession` to configure sound, and `AVAudioPlayer` to play different sounds.
I searched a lot and couldn't find anything. How can I manipulate output sources?

I need a method in my `SoundManager` where I could switch output between phone speaker and loudspeaker.

```
success = [session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker
                                     error:&error];
```

Using this I can route sound to loudspeaker, but there is no method to move it to phone speaker. Can anybody help me with it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, I found solution for manipulating with sound output.

You could initialize sound settings with `AVAudioSession`

Something like this:

```
session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

BOOL success;
NSError* error;

success = [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];

if (!success)  NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error setting category:%@",error);
success = [session setMode:AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat error:&error];

if (!success)  NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error setting mode:%@",error);

success = [session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:&error];

[session setPreferredOutputNumberOfChannels:0 error:nil];
if (!success)  NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error overrideOutputAudioPort:%@",error);

success = [session setActive:YES error:&error];
if (!success) NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error activating: %@",error);
else NSLog(@"audioSession active");
```

With

```
[session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:&error];
```

You set don't override output port. And your app playing with default speaker. As I understand for mode `AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat` used phone speaker. It's directly what I need for my SIP caller app.

Then you can override output port with

```
[session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:&error];
```

I do it so:

```
- (void) loudSpeakerOn:(BOOL)isLoudSpeaker{
    [session setActive:NO error:nil];

    BOOL success;
    NSError* error;

    success = [session overrideOutputAudioPort:isLoudSpeaker?AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:&error];

    if (!success)  NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error setting category:%@",error);

    [session setActive:YES error:nil];
}
```

Comment: But not playing sound while running this code. From ear speaker.