# Cannot initialise parameter

Tags: ios

I get this error:

> Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id' 
>   with an lvalue of type 'VDLPlaybackViewController *const __strong'

from this line of code:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: Could you post the snippet of the codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add this code in your `VDLPlaybackViewController.h`:

```
 @interface VDLPlaybackViewController: UIViewController <AVAudioSessionDelegate>
```

But `AVAudioSessionDelegate` was deprecated from `iOS6`:

```
/* The delegate property is deprecated. Instead, you should register for the NSNotifications named below. */
/* For example: 
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: myObject 
 selector:    @selector(handleInterruption:) 
 name:        AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification 
 object:      [AVAudioSession sharedInstance]]; 
 */
@property(assign) id<AVAudioSessionDelegate> delegate NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(4_0, 6_0);
```

Try to folow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25133772/avaudiosession-manipulate-sound-output) to initialize sound settings.