# Play music through ear speaker from user library

Tags: ios, swift, audio, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpmediaitemcollection

I'm making an app that allows the user to choose a music from his/her library and play it through the ear speaker. I got everything working, but this. I don't know how to play this audio through the ear speaker. The code I'm using to lay the audio is:

```
let player: MPMusicPlayerController! = MPMusicPlayerController.iPodMusicPlayer()
var mediaCollection: MPMediaItemCollection!

mediaCollection = mediaItemCollection
player.setQueueWithItemCollection(mediaCollection)

player.play()
```

If someone can help me it would be awesome, thanks in advance

**Edit:**
From what I've seen, this class `MpMusicPlayerController` is independent from my app, so it will ignore any instructions, right? So probably I can't play through the ear speaker with this class. Does anyone know how to play a library music through the ear speaker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an AVAudioSession to set the output to the ear speaker, but you would not be able to use MPMusicPlayerController to do it. See [AVAudioSession manipulate sound output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25133772/avaudiosession-manipulate-sound-output).

Comment: Yeah, I know. I've been able to do that. But the thing is, how can I use the AVAudioSession to play a music from the user library?

Comment: You can create an AVURLAsset from a MPMediaItem (get its URL with -[MPMediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL]) and then play that with an AVPlayer.

Comment: can you give me a hand Asset thing? I'm really confused trying to do it, can't find anything that helps