# In iOS, How to Play audio through speaker even when headset is plugged in?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, avaudiosession

**Function**: To disable headphone port or turn the headphone port off so that all audio plays from the speakers.

So even if headphone socket is in.. I want  to play ALL audio/sounds on the device speakers.
How can i implement this functionality?
Can i submit this type of application without having fear of any rejection.??

Thanks

Comment: Please take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25133772/avaudiosession-manipulate-sound-output/25203123#25203123

Comment: Please [attempt to search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+force+speaker) before posting a question.

Comment: I would say yes.  Refer to the HIG Sound section on headsets --> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Sound.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH44-SW1

Comment: The link goes directly to the sound section of the HIG...

Comment: Yes, But where is written that after implement this functionality apple can't reject the app? @Rufus

Comment: These are guidelines you should follow...so I'd say its a risk thats all.    Read the section specifically under -  Users use headsets and headphones to hear sounds privately and to free their hands. Regardless of whether these accessories are wired or wireless, users have specific expectations for the user experience.

Comment: No thx, thats all I have to say...